# How can I disambiguate strings and regexps in Elisp custom declarations?

Tags: regex, types, elisp

Consider the following Emacs Lisp code, which defines a customizable variable that can either be a literal string or a regular expression:

```
(defcustom myvar "" "String or regexp"
  :type '(choice (string :tag "String")
                 (regexp :tag "Regexp")))
```

This works just fine in the Custom interface `(customize-variable 'myvar)`, but it then becomes impossible to tell whether the variable was set to a string or a regular expression. Even the Custom interface thinks it's a string no matter what. If you set the variable to a regexp using Custom and then close and reopen the Custom buffer for the variable, it will once again say it's a string.

So, is there any way to disambiguate this, to ensure that when the variable is set to a regexp through Custom, my code can determine that it's meant to be a regexp and not a simple string?

Ideally, I would like some sort of mechanism to have the string be stored internally as `(cons 'string VALUE)`, where VALUE is the string that the user types in, and similarly have the regexp stored internally as `(cons 'regexp VALUE)`.

## Edit

From my searching, I've found the `:value-to-internal` and `:value-to-external` properties that you can supply to `define-widget`, but I can't figure out how to use them in a way that doesn't cause an error when I try to customize the resulting variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rephrasing my answer from [help-gnu-emacs](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2013-08/msg00465.html) --

Do what you suggested: use a `cons` instead of a string.

You need some way to programmatically distinguish arbitrary text from text used as a regexp. You know that intention at customize time: the user chooses one or the other.

You need to make sure that the user choice results in different (distinguishable) values. A `cons` recording (a) the text and (b) the type/choice/use is a good way to do that.

Comment: I figured out how to do what I want. I make creative use of the `:format` property to hide unnecessary repetitive information in the Customize interface. Essentially, since I'm already labeling the text field as either "String" or "Regexp". I hide the const using `:format ""`. So I have `(cons :tag "String" (const :format "" string) string)` for the string case, and analogously for the regexp case, and then I put them inside a `choice`. I'll be releasing the full code soon as part of a version 2.0 update to the [`ido-ubiquitous`](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/ido-ubiquitous) package.